# how to show the upload file in the template after return error when check the form

Tags: django, forms, file-upload, show

I have a form with file upload field, and this field will display in the template

after submit the form, if errors found and return back to the page, the upload file will disappear, can anyone help me about how to display the upload file in the form page after errors found

the following is the form:

```
class Project_f(forms.Form):
    info=forms.CharField(required=True)
    file=forms.FileField(required=False)
```

and the template:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" ....>
{% csrf_token %}

            <td ><label for="id_info">product info:</label></td>
            <td colspan=3 >{{form.info}}</td>   
            <td >&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_blank"></tr>
        <tr>
            <td >&nbsp;</td>
            <td><label for="id_attachement_id">add attachment:</label></td>
            {% if attachments %}
                {% for attachment in attachments %}
                <td colspan="2">
                current attachment：<div class='attachmentdd'id={{attachment.id}}><a href={{attachment.file}}>{{attachment.file}}</a>
                <br>modify：<input id="txt" class="input_text" type="file" name="attachement_id" style="width:100%;height:23px;">
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
            <td >{{form.attachement_id}}</td>   
            {% endif %}
            <td >&nbsp;</td>
        </tr></form>
```

The following is the views.py

```
Pr_form=Project_f(request.POST,request.FILES)
if Pr_form.is_valid():
      ......
else:
       c={'form': Pr_form,'user':login_name,'ourteam':ourteam}
       c.update(csrf(request))
       return  render_to_response('project_form.html',c,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

after submit the form, if errors found in the server, the upload file path will not display when show the error messages

Answer (score 0):

You can get information from the uploaded file by accessing it through the request.FILES dictionary in the view, then pass those variables to your template.

[update]

Ok, so based on the updated code from your views, here's an example of how you can get information out of the request.FILES collection, and how you can clean up your code a bit:

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render #assumes Django 1.3+

from your_app.forms import Project_f


def my_view(request):
    #always lower-case variable names, as classes are always capitalized
    pr_form = Project_f(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if pr_form.is_valid():
           my_file = request.FILES.get('my_file')
           file_name = my_file.name
           # do something with file_name, etc.

           pr_form.save()
    return render(request, 'project_form.html', {'form' : pr_form,
        'user' : login_name, 'ourteam' : ourteam})
```

Comment: What exactly did you try? It's hard to help with specific examples of what you're doing. The more information you can provide, the easier it will be for the community to help.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to get something out of request.FILES